# How can I set the height of my input field?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make some input field but I can't seem the get the height right. The height of the top one is good but the text is offsetted. I tried to change the height of the textstyle but it did not work. I tried to change the container height but it offsets the text. I tried to change the text height but it doesn't work. What can I do?

[image]

```
  Container
  (
    width: 200,
    height: 40,
    child: TextFormField
    (
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      decoration: InputDecoration
      (
        hintText: 'Enter your name',
        hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
        border: OutlineInputBorder
        (
          borderSide: BorderSide
          (
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder
        (
          borderSide: BorderSide
          (
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        )
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        return value.isEmpty ? 'Please enter your name' : null;
      },
    ),
  ),
  SizedBox(height: 10,),
  Container
  (
    width: 200,
    child: TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter your phone number',
        hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
        border: OutlineInputBorder
        (
          borderSide: BorderSide
          (
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder
        (
          borderSide: BorderSide
          (
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        )
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        return value.isEmpty ? 'Please enter your phone number' : null;
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset appear because you set the height of container smaller minimum height of TextField. You can fix it by increasing the height or reducing `contentPadding`. Like this

```
Container
        (
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          width: 200,
          height: 30,
          child: TextFormField
          (
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
            decoration: InputDecoration
            (
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              hintText: 'Enter your name',
              hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              border: OutlineInputBorder
              (
                gapPadding: 0.0,
                borderSide: BorderSide
                (
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
                  width: 2.0,
                ),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder
              (
                gapPadding: 0.0,
                borderSide: BorderSide
                (
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
                  width: 2.0,
                ),
              )
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              return value.isEmpty ? 'Please enter your name' : null;
            },
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Container
        (
          width: 200,
          child: TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter your phone number',
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              border: OutlineInputBorder
              (
                borderSide: BorderSide
                (
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
                  width: 2.0,
                ),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder
              (
                borderSide: BorderSide
                (
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, 
                  width: 2.0,
                ),
              )
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              return value.isEmpty ? 'Please enter your phone number' : null;
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter your name',
                  hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      width: 2.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      width: 2.0,
                    ),
                  )),
              validator: (value) {
                return value.isEmpty ? 'Please enter your name' : null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter your phone number',
                hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                return value.isEmpty
                    ? 'Please enter your phone number'
                    : null;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro wrap with `SizeBox` like this :

```
SizedBox(
    height: 45,
    child: TextField(
      enabled: enabled,
      textCapitalization: textCapitalization,
      onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
      obscureText: obscure,
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      style: AppTheme.normalTextStyle(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: textFieldPadding(),
        prefixIcon: perfixIcon,
        hintText: hint,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        hintStyle: AppTheme.normalTextStyle(),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0.0, color: HexColor("#F1F1F1")),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: HexColor("#F1F1F1")),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: HexColor("#F1F1F1")),
        ),
      ),
      inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(maxLength)],
      onTap: onTap,
      onSubmitted: onSubmit,
    ),
  );
```